# x.x is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't seem to be able to get the model in order to create a new object of type picture. Here's some of the code that I'm using.

for the endṕoint:

```
import { picture } from '../models/pictures'
//etc..

pics.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
upload.single('image')(req, res, (err) => {
  if(err){
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  } else {
    if(req.file == undefined){
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'upload a valid file!' });
    } else {
      var pic = new picture({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        filename: req.body.databasepicname,
      });
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'woo!' })
      };
    }
  });
```

});

for the model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from './users'

const pictureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, maxlength: [50, 'Title must be longer than 50 characters']},
    description: {type: String},
    filename: {tpe: String},
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});

var picture = mongoose.model('Picture', pictureSchema);

exports = picture;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: what is x.x ? can you share the whole error you get ?

Comment: it seems like you are exporting picture the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model file you're providing a default export, but in your endpoint file you're expecting a named export:

```
// models/pictures.js
export = picture;

// endpoint.js
import { picture } from '../models/pictures';
```

Try changing it to this (using a named export in both files):

```
// models/pictures.js
export.picture = picture;

// endpoint.js
import { picture } from '../models/pictures';
```

Or this (using a default export in both files):

```
// models/pictures.js
export = picture;

// endpoint.js
import picture from '../models/pictures';
```

Comment: Yup. That was it.